# Better to maintain a list in datastore or csv file?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I want to maintain an email blacklist of people who don't want to ever receive email from my service.

Before I send each email, I want to do a lookup on whether the recipient is in the list.

Which of 2 choices is better?

1. I can create a BlacklistEmail model in datastore and key it on the email address so I can have faster lookups using get_by_id(). In 99% of cases, the recipient will not be in the blacklist so this would actually cost a read as it would not hit memcache.
2. I can store the blacklisted email in a csv file and check whether the recipient is in the list. This seems like it wouldn't cost anything, but I am not sure about performance. I don't expect the list to be very big.
3. Any other better way?

Which is better in terms of cost and performance?

Comment: How big is the blacklist going to get?

Comment: It would help to know whether you're planning on sending email in batches to many recipients, or ad-hoc to individual recipients.  When you say you don't expect the list to be very big, are you talking ~10s, ~100s or ~1000s?  Would you be intending to store the CSV in Cloud Storage?

Comment: The list will probably less than 1,000 emails. Most emails will be sent ad-hoc. There will be some cases of a batched blast such as a user wide service announcement. Yes, storing in Cloud Storage would be an option.

Answer (score 1):

As tx802 pointed, I believe you mean to store the CSV in Cloud Storage. Are we right?

In such a case, it could be an option, but a strange one. Mostly if it suits some other workflow that you have and you do not care that much about super performance and you do not update it that much often. Of course use a global variable or Memcache in front of it and cross your fingers so it doesn't get flushed.

Anyway, this option doesn't escalate well. What I would recommend is you go by option 3). Use Memcache[1] for quick lookup and back it up with Datastore, which has also good performance.

There is something else to consider. Should you store/work_with/query the full list or with separate objects/entities?

It depends mostly on the size and amount of information stored on the list.
Datastore and Memcache both have a limit of 1MB imposed on its objects. If you cannot fit the list there, you will have to split it into separate entities.

I hope it helps. Happy coding!

[1] https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/#Python_When_to_use_a_memory_cache

Answer (score 0):

As I know get_by_id() (small) operations are free of charge. So you will pay only for instance hours. But I think it would be better to store subscription emails in another kind, because storage is cheap, and denormalization of data is a good practice on GAE. Anyway CSV does not looks like a good idea.